# Accessing deleted answers behaviour doesn't match accessing deleted questions behaviour

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, sharing

When you share a link to a question that gets deleted, any user without enough reputation sees a page that states the question had been there but is now removed. (I'm assuming the ability to see deleted answers is defined by the reputation but it doesn't make any difference, though).

However, when you share a link to an answer that gets deleted, navigating to that link will get you to the question without any notice that the link is actually an answer that got deleted. I can confirm in this case that if you have reputation enough you can see the question. However, when sharing via any social network, it won't be the case for most users.

Shouldn't this answers behaviour be similar to the questions one?

PS: Just an additional and probably unrelated question: Does it make sense to be able to share deleted Q&A? I know you could get around this by first sharing and then deleting but not allowing the user to share deleted Q&A would at least make things harder for the user to brake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think a notice box at the top of the question, for users without the privilege to view the answer, would be useful here:

> The answer you were looking for has been [removed for reasons of moderation / voluntarily removed by its author], but the question is still here for you to view.

---

As far as sharing deleted content - it does have its uses. Meta is the primary example. The share button is a quick way to get a direct link to something so that users on Meta who would be able to see the deleted post can quickly get to it. There's certainly no big reason to disable the button on deleted posts. What harm is it doing?

Comment: This feature is insanely overdue - by now I know that when i click an answer link and end up seeing the question, I know it is a deleted answer, but not everyone will know this

Comment: +1 a simpler implementation, however, would be to just have all questions with deleted answers say so to lower-rep users. I understand why we only want to show the deleted answers themselves, but revealing the count should not require such privilege.

Comment: @Aaron But my revealing that there are other answers on each question would only spark curiosity and complaints that they can't see an answer which could potentially solve the problem. If you already *know* there's another answer there, it makes sense to say why you can't see it. Otherwise it makes sense to pretend it's not there.

Comment: Meh, same stuff you get when people complain they can't leave a comment or can't figure out why their question has been closed. If the general disclaimer states that answers have been deleted for any of reasons (a), (b) or (c) I don't see the problem. Anyway, I only offered that as a workaround if implementing the per-question and per-rep check proved challenging (which it shouldn't, because that already drives the decision to show deleted answers).